# How do I pass the value of a variable through the components in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, var

That's my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";

import Particles from './components/particles'
import Title from './components/start'
import Explain from "./components/explain"
import "./App.css"
import Test from "./components/test"
import Test1 from "./components/IntLin/test1"
import Test2 from "./components/IntLin/test2"
import Test3 from "./components/IntLin/test3"

export default class App extends Component{

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div className="start">
          <Particles/>
          <Route exact path="/inicio" render={() => {
          return <div className="titulo">
          <Title}/>
          </div>
          }}>
          </Route>
        </div>
          <Route exact path="/explain" render={() => {                    
            return <div className="explain">
              <Explain}/>
            </div>
            }}>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/test" render={() => {
            return <div className="test">
              <Test/>
            </div>
          }}>
          </Route>
           <Route exact path="/test1" render={() => {
              return <div className="test1">
                <Test1/>
              </div>
            }}>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/test2" render={() => {
              return <div className="test2">
                <Test2/>
              </div>
            }}>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/test3" render={() => {
              return <div className="test3">
                <Test3/>
              </div>
            }}>
            </Route>
        </Router>
      </div>
      );
  };

}
```

So, basically I want to set a numeric variable in app.js, then when I go to the 'Test' component I can find the variable and add +1 and then the next component 'Test1' can subtract -1 and so on through all the components until you reach the final component where you will get how much was the final variable.

Comment: To pass the data that is consumed by a single component from parent to child (nested up to couple levels down) you may use props (pass parent's state as a prop to child components). If data consuming component is nested deeper, you may use React Context. If data is required by multiple scattered components, you may employ state management tool, like Redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use both passing props or `Context` but what you really want to do is to pass a two or three things.

1. variable
2. incremeant funciton
3. decrement function

or you can combine number 2 and 3 :)

here is the example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/74qzy90m3x

Comment: I'm going to add that I'm using local state here and you can refactor the app later to use Context and even refactor this code to use hooks. A good place to learn React, Context and Hooks is egghead